# Give a value to an ng-model="searchText" input based on list item clicked in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, filter, angularjs

I created a list that is searchable with an input using angular.js (ng-model="searchText"). On click of the list elements you can pull the content of the selected item using {{selected | json}}. I want to apply this selected element as the value of the input when a list item is clicked.

I essentially want to create my own autocomplete that always displays a list of options, filters options while typing, and fills in the input on click of an option.

HTML

```
<html ng-app> 
<section>
   <div id="content-body" class="container search-page"><!-- begin content-body -->
    <div id="content-frame" class="container"></div><!-- end content-frame -->
      <section>
        <div class="search-container">
          <div class="search-wrapper">
            <input type="search" class="input-from" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText" value="{{searchText}}">
          </div> 
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
          <ul class="list-group search">
        <!--<li class="list-group-item group-title">
                <span class="icon itinerary-icon"></span>
                Popular Destinations
            </li>-->
              <a ng-click="setMaster(cities)" ng-repeat="city in cities | filter:searchText | limitTo:limit" href="#" class="list-group-item">{{city}}</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
   </div><!-- end content-body -->
</html>
```

JS

```
function ContentCtrl($scope, $http) {
    "use strict";

    $scope.url = '../mobile-site/cities.json';
    $scope.cities = [];
    $scope.limit = 10; // max 10 cities loaded

    $scope.fetchContent = function() {
        $http.get($scope.url).then(function(response){
            $scope.cities = response.data.cities; 
        });
    }

    $scope.fetchContent(); // build cities list

    $scope.setMaster = function(city) {
            $scope.searchText = city; // pull selected city using {{selected | json}}
        }
    }
```

JSON

```
{
"version": "082B6AF45261B81358E8F99F0FAEC4A4",
"cities": [
"A Friela Maside, Spain",
"A Gudina, Spain",
"AHA, Germany",
"AL, Norway"
]
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want the value of the input which you are filtering with to take the value of the clicked item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a few mistakes in the code:

```
<div ng-model="chosen">
    <a ng-click="setMaster(cities)" ng-repeat="cities in cities | filter:searchText | limitTo:limit" href="#" class="list-group-item">{{cities}}</a>
</div>
```

shoud be

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities | filter:searchText | limitTo:limit">
    <a ng-click="setMaster(city)" class="list-group-item">{{city}}</a>
</div>
```

then I think what you want is

```
$scope.setMaster = function(city) {
    $scope.searchText = city;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what the ng-model on the div is for, as far as I know it is used only for inputs, textareas and selects. See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel).

You probably want something like this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/weSpW/3/.

Comment: It is not a mistake in my code, I added my JSON up top so you can see. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: the element you use for repeating is the same as the array which you are repeating on -> ng-repeat="cities in cities" should be ng-repeat="city in cities"

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. I updated my code up top thanks.

Comment: @mcestone - look at the fiddle I posted. Maybe that will help you out.

Comment: Absolutely amazing! That is exactly what I need. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, in you example you have to use $rootScope to access the model of the input because it does not belong to a specific controller, however, you should be better off by including the input inside the inital controller so you don't have to use the $rootScope, like this [http://jsfiddle.net/weSpW/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/weSpW/3/)